# Unbind Error on fancyBox Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

This only happens on selected sites. I have a bookmarklet. I go to open a box when the user clicks and get this error:

[image]

It would seem that the a.wrap part of the expression would guard against undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is pretty simple: the statement is an `and` and it should be an `or`.

Update: ok, turns out this is what worked:

```
    if( a.wrap !=null && typeof a.wrap != "undefined" && typeof a.wrap.unbind != "undefined") {
            a.wrap.unbind(".fb");
      }
```

instead of:

```
    unbindEvents : function() {
        a.wrap && a.wrap.unbind(".fb");
```

Per this [link](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/12/software-sins-of-omission/): 30% of defects are logic errors.